# CS0433 error (System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector) when running automated build on TeamCity using MSBuild

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, teamcity

I have a C# assembly project containing a WPF GUI.
When compiling on my development machine, everything works fine.
When I compile it on a TeamCity agent using MSBuild, I get the following error:

```
error CS0433: The type 'System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector' exists in both
'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'
 and 'c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\WindowsBase.dll'
```

However, when compiling the project manually in VS2012 on the mentioned build machine, it also works fine.
What may be the issue? Can I resolve it by setting some compiler flags or do I have to rewrite my code in order to get this work with automated builds?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have found a workaround. Changing the buildrunner on teamcity from *MSBuild* to *Visual Studio (sln)* resulted in a successful compilation.